# Combining MvxSidebarPresentation with MvxTabBarViewController

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am searching for a current solution for the issue stated at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1941.

We want to have the `MvxSidebarPresentation` throughout the whole app, but applying it with a `MvxTabBarViewController` does not work. At the moment the only solution is to deactivate the `MvxSidebarPresentation` for those Views completely.

Is there any pretty workaround or a solution by now? Or could you state me to ways how to solve it myself?